# Max sql server without group by

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

```
    CallID  StartTime           EndTime                 Querytime
    1692    2012-11-20 11:52:00.000 2012-11-20 11:52:00.300 0.300
    1693    2012-11-20 11:52:00.000 2012-11-20 11:52:00.100 0.100
    1694    2012-11-20 11:52:00.000 2012-11-20 11:52:00.400 1.5
    1695    2012-11-20 11:52:01.000 2012-11-20 11:52:01.400 3
    1696    2012-11-20 11:52:01.000 2012-11-20 11:52:01.300 5
```

I would like to get the maximum querytime grouped by the StartTime like below but i still want CallID to be shown.

```
     StartTime                  MaxQueryTime
     2012-11-11 19:04:07.000    0.300
     2012-11-11 19:04:10.000    0.200
     2012-11-11 19:08:48.000    0.300
     2012-11-11 19:08:51.000    0.300
     2012-11-11 19:09:27.000    0.100

     SELECT     StartTime, MAX(Querytime) AS QueryTime
     FROM         dbo.Calls
     GROUP BY StartTime
```

Comment: What do you want to see if two query times are the same for the same start time?

Comment: if callid is in calls then simply add CallID after SELECT and before StartTime,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH records
AS
(
    SELECT  CallID, StartTime, EndTime, QueryTime,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY QueryTime DESC) rn
    FROM    TableName
)
SELECT CallID, StartTime, EndTime, QueryTime
FROM records
WHERE rn = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e749a/2)
- [TSQL Ranking Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
select CallID, StartTime, max(QueryTime) over (partition by StartTime) as QueryTime
from (
    SELECT CallID, StartTime, MAX(Querytime) as QueryTime
    FROM dbo.Calls
    GROUP BY CallID, StartTime
 ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

And try this :

> select CallID,StartTime,EndTime, QueryTime 
> from dbo.Calls as CLL
> where CLL.QueryTime =
>
> > (Select top 1 dbo.Calls.QueryTime from dbo.Calls where dbo.Calls.StartTime = CLL.StartTime order by  dbo.Calls.QueryTime desc )
>
> group by CLL.CallID,CLL.StartTime,CLL.EndTime,CLL.QueryTime
> order by CLL.StartTime -- you can refuse this line